# how can I draw only one vector (at a specific point) of the gradient in the Contour Plot?

Tags: plotting, vector

I already have draw the Contour Plot and I know how Vector Plot a field of vectors.
But the problem is how can I draw only one vector (at a specific point) of the gradient in the Contour Plot?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that uses `Epilog` and `Arrow` to add a single vector to a contour plot.  The vector represents the gradient of the function that is being plotted.  The `Grad` function is used to calculate the gradient.

```
f[x_, y_] := Sin[x] + Cos[y]
r = {x -> Pi/2, y -> 2.1};
pt1 = {x, y} /. r;
pt2 = pt1 + Grad[f[x, y], {x, y}] /. r;
ContourPlot[f[x, y] == 1/2, {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi},
 Epilog -> {Red, Arrow[{pt1, pt2}]}]
```